# Uppercase every, every second or every third word in a string

Tags: c#, uppercase

I only know that `ToUpper()` converts all words to uppercase, but what if I would like to convert only every second or every third or even every forth words and so on in a string? What method should I use?

Comment: What coding language are you using dear?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You need to be more precise. In which context, in what language - are we talking "words", or are we talking characters?

Comment: @TroyOops, sorry my bad! It was C#.

Comment: @davidkonrad Yes, just actual "words", as simple string

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your code language.

You can use simple loop:

```
int gap = 2;
// Array indexed from 0, if in your language it starts from 1
// replace 'gap-1' with 'gap'
for (int i = gap-1; i < lengthOfYourString; i+=gap) {
    yourstring[i] = yourstring[i].toupper();
}
```

This snippet will make every second character uppercase.

This snippet will NOT work in your language, if you specify the coding language i will edit the answer

Comment: Hi, I'm writing in C#. I'm using `StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("Day.txt")` and file contains a simple sentence. I'm trying to convert every second (or other number) word to uppercase.

Comment: This will not work in C# since strings are immutable, you cannot change the value in a string at any given address ie yourstring[i] = BLAH is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Whichever language you are using then I doubt there will be any built-in function to convert every other word in a sentence, so you'd need to write your own logic.

Here is an example (written in C#) that will uppercase every other word in a sentence, given that the sentence 'words' are divided up by spaces

```
var words = sentence.Split(" ");
var output = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var index = 0; index < words.length; index++) {
    if (index % 2 == 0)
        output.Append(words[index].ToUpper());
    else
        output.Append(words[index]);
}
```

Comment: Stop using 'index%2', you can increment your counter with a number too, not just 'index++', like 'index+=2' so you can improve perfomance by removing a whole condition.